# Vertical progress bar has strange background which is not changeable

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

The progress bar is created by the following code

```
    bar = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.VERTICAL);
    bar.setEnabled(true);

    bar.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    bar.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

    bar.setStringPainted(true);     

    getReflectedComponent().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getReflectedComponent().add(bar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Note that getReflectedComponent() returns a JComponent. In another method the displayed String the max value and the current value are manipulated, not more.

I really have no idea why this very strange grey stripes are displayed at the top. If I display the progress bar horizontally they are not there...

[image: This is how my progress bar looks like]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I don't observe your problem with your code so it must come from something else that you are not showing us (one more argument to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Here is an example to get yourself started:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestScrollbars {

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle(TestScrollbars.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.VERTICAL);
        bar.setEnabled(true);

        bar.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        bar.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

        bar.setStringPainted(true);
        bar.setString("2000 g");
        bar.setValue(65);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(bar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestScrollbars().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the resulting image (where progress bar is correctly displaying the chosen colors):

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Also consider a custom `ProgressBarUI`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465982/230513) and shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886795/230513).

[image]